# Git - move commit from 1 branch to another

Tags: git

I have two branches:

```
develop
myFeature
```

I have made a single commit incorrectly while on develop and should have been on myFeature.

The commit has not been pushed yet.

How can i move this commit from develop and onto myFeature?

Comment: If it was the last commit made to `develop`, you could just do a soft reset on your head back one commit (while `develop` is checked out), which removes the commit from `develop` but keeps the edits in your local workspace. Then you can checkout `myFeature` (assuming no conflicts will arise), and commit/push the local workspace edits to the feature branch from there.

Answer (score 11):

```
git checkout myFeature
git cherry-pick develop
git checkout -B develop develop~
```